# How Much Solar Wind Does A Star Produce?

Tags: stars, worldbuilding-resources, astrophysics, mathematics

I need someone to give me a way to figure out how fast the solar wind from a star with a known mass travels, as well as how much solar wind the star releases in a given amount of time. I hope that it helps me determine how magnetic a planet needs to be when orbiting a star that’s not the sun to not get its atmosphere sheared off by the solar wind.

Comment: @ARogueAnt. Thanks.

Comment: [Astronomy Stack Exchange](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/). (And it all depends on the atmosphere, doesn't it? For example, Venus has a massive atmosphere, although it doesn't have any magnetic field to speak of, and being closer to the Sun it experiences a much stronger solar wind than Earth. True, there is no water in Venus's atmosphere, due to photodissociation and hydrogen being blown off.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a difficult (but interesting!) question to answer, and strongly depends on the star in question. In general, hot, massive stars have higher mass-loss rates and higher terminal velocities then lower-mass stars, but that may change as a star evolves. For instance, stars like the Sun eventually evolve off the main sequence into [asymptotic giant branch stars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_giant_branch), which may lose up to $10^{-4}M_{\odot}$ per year, which is about ten orders of magnitude more than on the main sequence. Other difficulties arise because there's no universally applicable wind mechanism; massive stars tend to have radiation-driven winds, while less-massive stars may have thermally-driven winds arising from pressure gradients.

Here's a table of the wind properties of a set of stars, which I pulled from [an earlier answer of mine](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/116174/627). HD 93129Aa and Deneb are supergiants, while the rest are main sequence stars. I've sorted them by spectral type, but if you sort by mass, you'll notice that in general, lower-mass stars have lower mass-loss rates $\dot{M}$ and lower terminal velocities $v_{\infty}$.

$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}\hline
\text{Star} & \text{Stellar type} & \text{Mass }(M_{\odot}) & \dot{M}(M_{\odot}\text{ yr}^{-1}) & v_{\infty}(\text{km/s})\\\hline
\text{HD 93129Aa}^1 & \text{O2} & 95 & 2\times10^{-5} & 3200\\\hline
\tau\text{ Sco}^2 & \text{B0} & 20 & 3.1\times10^{-8} & 2400\\\hline
\sigma\text{ Ori E}^3 & \text{B2} & 8.9 & 2.4\times10^{-9} & 1460\\\hline
\alpha\text{ Col}^2 & \text{B7} & 3.7 & 3\times10^{-12} & 1250\\\hline
\text{Deneb}^4 & \text{A2} & 20 & 10^{-6} & 225\\\hline
\text{Sun} & \text{G2} & 1 & 10^{-14} & 400\\\hline
\text{Proxima Centauri}^5 & \text{M6} & 0.12 & 10^{-13} & 550\\\hline
\end{array}
$$
<sub><sup>1</sup>[Cohen et al. (2011)](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2011MNRAS.415.3354C), <sup>2</sup>[Cohen et al. (1997)](http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1086/304636/fulltext/), <sup>3</sup>[Krtička et al. (2006)](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2006A%26A...460..145K), <sup>4</sup>[Aufdenberg et al. (2002)](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2002ApJ...570..344A), <sup>5</sup>[Wargelin & Drake (2002)](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2002ApJ...578..503W)</sub>

As you might expect, the speed and density of the wind aren't constant at all points around a star. Spherical symmetry is often a good choice (although rotation and magnetic fields can complicate this close to the star's surface). With a couple of additional assumptions, we get the following expressions for the density of a star's wind $\rho$ and the wind speed $v$ at a radius $r$:
$$\rho(r)=\frac{\dot{M}}{4\pi r^2v(r)},\quad v(r)=v_{\infty}\left(1-\frac{R_*}{r}\right)^{\beta}$$
The latter is something of an assumption, but it does work reasonably well, particularly for massive stars, where we usually assume $\beta\approx1$.

I assume you're looking at a lower mass Sun-like star for the sake of habitability, so a mass-loss rate of $\sim10^{-13}M_{\odot}$ per year and a terminal velocity in the range of 400-500 km/s would be reasonable. You can then calculate the density and speed at the orbital radius of the planet.

Comment: Thanks for giving me an answer. I’ll be using your formulas later.